# access columns of a data object by column index using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table customer, with columns [a1,a2,a3,...a10]
I need to access them by number, for example to set a3 ,a4 , a5  values , using a numbers instead of their real name like customer[4] = 1 .
is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, and what kind of "linq" are you using?

Answer (score 0):

See this link:
[Generic Field and SetField Methods (LINQ to DataSet)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386916%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Edit 1:

The information provided by you is limited

This code may help you

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

starting with reflection (note, this is slowish - OK for moderate amounts of data though):

```
var customer = new Customer();
var props = customer.GetType().GetProperties();
props[0].SetValue(customer, 1);
props[1].SetValue(customer, "hamix");
Console.WriteLine(props[0].GetValue(customer));
Console.WriteLine(props[1].GetValue(customer));
```

Comment: I think I need different code.suppose I created an object of type Customers(name of my table) and now I want to have a code like this:
customers cust = new customers();
for( 1 to 10)
cust[i] = something;
which cust[i] is a filed of my customer table!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by an [*indexed property*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx):

```
class Customer
{
    private static PropertyInfo[] _propertyInfos 
        = typeof(Customer).GetProperties()
                          .Where (x => x.Name.StartsWith("A")).ToArray();

    public int A1 { get; set; }
    public int A2 { get; set; }
    public int A3 { get; set; }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)(_propertyInfos[index - 1].GetValue(this) ?? 0);
        }
        set
        {
            _propertyInfos[index - 1].SetValue(this, value);
        }
    }
}
```

(leaving out bounds checks of the `_propertyInfos` array)

However, I doubt if you should go this path. The design smells like bad normalization.